# Find text (Hex) between two string

Tags: java, string, hex

I am trying to find text between two string using some given examples here I am able to do so in specific case but when it comes to hex(using same identifiers) I am getting error.
Please guide me to get value between....  sample and error given below...
Note- I have large text(complete text files 9999 words approx) I only provided sample text which works normally

```
private static void modifyText() {
       String str1 = "private final byte[] record1 = new byte[]{sdfjsdkhfkjsdf hgb sdjfkhsdkfsdf |sdfjksdhfjksd sdf sdkjfhsdkf | sdkjfh hgb sdkjfdshfks|}";
          String result1 = str1.substring(str1.indexOf("byte[] record1 = new byte[]{") , str1.indexOf("}"));
          System.out.println("\n found1\n"+result1);

      String pattern1 = "record1 = new byte[]{";
      String pattern2 = "}";

       String text= "private final byte[] record1 = new byte[]{\r\n (byte)0x70,(byte)0x80}"; //**for small text it is working**   

      String result = text.substring(text.indexOf(pattern1) + 1, text.indexOf(pattern2));

      System.out.println("\n found2\n"+result);
  }
```

found1 prints perfectly below 
        byte[] record1 = new byte[]{sdfjsdkhfkjsdf hgb sdjfkhsdkfsdf |sdfjksdhfjksd sdf sdkjfhsdkf | sdkjfh hgb sdkjfdshfks|

while found 2 says error -------
     java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -799
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)

Comment: It works fine on my computer\

Comment: This also works for me but when I am passing full file (java class file with text ) then it breaks....

Comment: It seems your actual program generates negative indices. Error says a problem with index -799. String indices are always non-negative (i.e. `>= 0`).